# Why Spring Batch didn't support Sybase as a dataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sybase

I am trying to use Spring Batch in my project following [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) with Sybase.

However, it seems that @EnableBatchProcessing will invoke the batchInitialization and it requires every type of dataSource to be present in DatabaseDriver.java [(github link here)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DatabaseDriver.java). The result is that Spring batch throws this error

```
'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type'
```

Is there a specific reason why Sybase is not supported?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9147 It is also raised in here.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by adding below line to application.properties

```
spring.batch.schema=classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sybase.sql
```

Batch initialisation will skip looping through DatabaseDriver.java as described in the question and directly start creating necessary DB tables for Spring batch processing in Sybase DB.